# Paste corresponding characters from multiple lines together

Tags: linux, bash

I'm writing a linux-command that pasts corresponding characters from multiple lines together. For example: I want to change these lines

```
A---
-B--
---C
--D-
```

to this:

```
A----B-----D--C-
```

So far, i've made this:

```
cat sanger.a sanger.c sanger.g sanger.t | cut -c 1
```

This does the trick for only the first column, but it has to work for all the columns.

Is there anyone who can help?

EDIT: This is a better example. I want this:

> SUGAR
>
> HONEY
>
> CANDY

to become

> SHC UOA GND AED RYY (without spaces)

Comment: You want to create one long line from all the input lines but sorted by which "field" is actually filled out?

Comment: Why does c have a - on the end ?Are the lines in different files ?

Comment: why does the output have `D` before `C`?

Comment: @fedorqui i think OP wants it in the order the letters appear in the fields.

Comment: Are all lines guaranteed to have the same length, and if not, what should happen if they don't?

Comment: They are guaranteed to have the same length. No need to bother about lines with different length

Comment: This is going to be fun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All right, time for some sed insanity! :D

**Disclaimer: If this is for something serious, use something less brittle than this.** awk comes to mind. Unless you feel confident enough in your sed abilities to maintain this lunacy.

```
cat file1 file2 etc | sed -n '1h; 1!H; $ { :loop; g; s/$/\n/; s/\([^\n]\)[^\n]*\n/\1/g; p; g; s/^.//; s/\n./\n/g; h; /[^\n]/ b loop }' | tr -d '\n'; echo
```

This comes in three parts: Say you have a file `foo.txt`

```
12345
67890
abcde
fghij
```

then

```
cat foo.txt | sed -n '1h; 1!H; $ { :loop; g; s/$/\n/; s/\([^\n]\)[^\n]*\n/\1/g; p; g; s/^.//; s/\n./\n/g; h; /[^\n]/ b loop }'
```

produces

```
16af
27bg
38ch
49di
50ej
```

After that, `tr -d '\n'` deletes the newlines, and `;echo` adds one at the end.

The heart of this madness is the sed code, which is

```
1h
1!H
$ {
  :loop
  g
  s/$/\n/
  s/\([^\n]\)[^\n]*\n/\1/g
  p
  g
  s/^.//
  s/\n./\n/g
  h
  /[^\n]/ b loop
}
```

This first follows the basic pattern

```
1h          # if this is the first line, put it in the hold buffer
1!H         # if it is not the first line, append it to the hold buffer
$ {         # if this is the last line, 
  do stuff  # do stuff. The whole input is in the hold buffer here.
}
```

which assembles all input in the hold buffer before working on it. Once the whole input is in the hold buffer, this happens:

```
  :loop
  g                         # copy the hold buffer to the pattern space
  s/$/\n/                   # put a newline at the end
  s/\([^\n]\)[^\n]*\n/\1/g  # replace every line with only its first character
  p                         # print that
  g                         # get the hold buffer again
  s/^.//                    # remove the first character from the first line
  s/\n./\n/g                # remove the first character from all other lines
  h                         # put that back in the hold buffer
  /[^\n]/ b loop            # if there's something left other than newlines, loop
```

And there you have it. I might just have summoned Cthulhu.

Comment: Thanks, but Jidder's awk solution is much, much saner. You should probably go with that. I have to admit I did this mostly for the fun of playing with sed (it's like a puzzle game sometimes). If you're interested in it, [here](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)'s a great site to start (and to look things up).

Comment: @Wintermute Apparently sed isn't a `programmable filter` like awk! Nah but seriously nice answer, answers like this remind i still need to have a proper look at sed :)

Answer (score 1):

Awk way for updated spec

```
awk -vFS= '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)a[i]=a[i]$i}
           END{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf "%s",a[i];print ""}' file
```

Output

```
A----B-----D--C-

SHCUOAGNNAEDRYY
```

P.s for a large file this will use lots of memory

A terrible way not using awk, also you need to know the number of fields before hand.

```
for i in {1..4};do cut -c $i test | tr -d "\n" ; done;echo
```

Comment: I want it to do this: Take character 1 from first line, take character 1 from second line and put them together in this order ch1line1 ch1line2 ch2line1 ch2line2 ch3line1 ch3line2 if you understand what I mean. It has to join the lines read from top to bottom per character.

Comment: This does the trick. Thank you very much! I wonder however if it's possible to do this without awk and a temp file?

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt Don't know what you mean ?

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the same output by only using things such as sort, sed, cut and other commands without programmable filters such as awk?

Comment: @PieterVerschaffelt Is there a specific reason for this ?

Comment: @Pieter awk is a tool just the same as the others you have mentioned, it just happens to be a more powerful one. If you have a specific reason for your requirement, please add it to your question.

Comment: Yes, I'm practicing for my exams later this week and I have spent several hours on this exercise without being able to solve it. We haven't learned awk yet, so I think it has to be possible to fix this without awk.

Comment: Alternative without `awk` which counts the columns in the file: `paste -s -d "" <(for i in $(seq 1 $(wc -L < f)); do cut -c $i f; done)` (note: `wc -L` is a GNUism)

Comment: @JoshJolly Post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution without `awk` or `sed`, assuming the file is named `f`:

```
paste -s -d "" <(for i in $(seq 1 $(wc -L < f)); do cut -c $i f; done)
```

`wc -L` is a GNUism which returns the length of the longest line in the input file, which might not work depending on your version/locale. You could instead find the longest line by doing something like:

```
awk '{if (length > x) {x = length}} END {print x}' f
```

Then using this value in the `seq` command instead of the above command substitution.